# Excel - Find where there is a jump in value in a colum

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find where there is a large jump in data in just 1 column.

From the example data in the column below, the value changes between the cells, but I want to retrieve the row number 6, because there was a larger jump from 5 to 6.

```
1    2.688

2    2.681

3    2.688

4    2.681

5    2.688

**6    2.525**

7    2.519

8    2.506

9    2.513
```

I tried the following:

```
=MATCH(MAX(ABS(A2:A9-A1:A8)),ABS(A2:A9-A1:A8),0)
```

But I don't understand, it just returns #N/A. I tried the debugger, but it shows the result of ABS to be 0 on each. Please Guide me

If I have the opposite, like `1.331 1.338 1.331 1.344 1.325 1.325 1.325` How can I return the row number for where it goes from `1.344` to `1.325`?

Comment: Define '*relatively large jump*' as a number. Do you mean the '*largest jump*' ?

Comment: Yes I mean largest. So in my dataset 6 is where the largest jump is. Thanks

Comment: Do you get the correct results when you use [ctrl]+[shift]+[enter] instead of just [enter] to finalize the formula?

Comment: Oh Wow, yes. Sorry for stupid question but what does  [ctrl]+[shift]+[enter] do?

Comment: That's called the Excel magic. It will turn your simple formula into Array formula.

Comment: That's not a stupid question!  That turns a formula into an [Array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7). Generally, "An array formula is a formula that can perform multiple calculations on one or more of the items in an array."  These can be quite useful and powerful, so I suggest searching around for "Excel Array Formulas" when you have some time, and see what you can do with them.  I use them when doing a [multiple criteria Index/Match](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/)

Comment: And If I have the opposite, like 1.331
1.338
1.331
1.344
1.325
1.325
1.325

How can I return the row number for where it goes from 1.344 to 1.325?